# Python control multiple py script runtime with panel

Tags: python

I have written multiple python scripts that are run concurrently and regularly by ThreadPool.
I'm wondering is there any frame which I can **overview** the scripts and **control** when and how the scripts run.
By the way,APScheduler is not the way.What I want is control and overview the whole scripts status.

Comment: You can try simple-scheduler. https://pypi.org/project/simple_scheduler/. I think it might work for you.

Comment: oky.I try it right away.